# Will bottom pressure decrease?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

This is a problem I have struggling with. I’ve been discussing it with friends.
Consider a boat in a swimming pool with a heavy rock on it. If we throw the rock into the pool, it'll sink. Through some thoughs we conclude that the level of the water will go down (and assume that it'll decrease considerably). My question is, will bottom pressure decrease?
My first thougt was yes, becuase $ρgh_1<ρgh_0$. But a professor is making me doubt about that. She says that because total mass doesn't change, pression at the bottom is going to be the same as first, and applies Pascal’s Principle, then it will invalidate the formula ρgh.

Comment: The pressure on the bottom of the pool depends ONLY on the depth of water in the pool.

Comment: And on the pressure (e.g., atmospheric) at the free surface of the pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Bottom pressure” is vague. The *total force on the bottom* is the same whether the rock is in the boat or on the bottom; we can show this with a free-body diagram that includes the water, boat, and rock.

Since the area of the bottom is a constant, the *average pressure on the bottom* is the same after dropping the rock.

However, the *water pressure at the bottom* is lower if the water level drops for any reason, including dropping the rock. (The heavy rock resting on the bottom makes up the difference regarding the total force and average pressure.)

Does this clarify things? Perhaps people are referring to different “bottom pressures.”

Answer (score 1):

> Through some thoughts we conclude that the level of the water will go down

Here's another way to visualize that part of the problem:

Instead of simply throwing the rock over the side, let's take it in stages. Let's start by tying a rope to the rock, and hanging it over the side. Boat and rock together still weigh the same as before. Boat and rock still are supported entirely by buoyancy because no part of the boat or the rock is touching the bottom.

OK? let's let out some rope—enough so that the rock is almost but not quite touching bottom. Maybe there's just a thousandth of a millimeter to go before it touches. The rope still is under tension, the boat still is supporting the full weight of the rock.

Now, cut the rope. The rock hardly moves at all—a thousandth of a millimeter, not even enough to see—but the boat suddenly is freed from supporting the rock's weight. What happens to the boat when all that weight is released? What happens to the water level?

Comment: The water level drops because the boat would rise suddenly, dislodging less water, due to the appearance of the normal force exerted by the bottom on the rock. Before releasing the rope, wouldn't the boat carry the weight of the rock minus the push that the water exerts on it, because the rock under the water "would be lighter"?

Comment: @EsauUV Yes, When the rock is sitting in the boat, it exerts more downward force on the boat because it is not buoyed by the water than in the case where the rock is dangling from the boat under the surface. But either way, when nothing is resting on the bottom, the buoyant force on Boat+Rock must be exactly equal to the weight of Boat+Rock. If it were not exactly equal, then the boat and the rock would either rise up or sink lower as needed until an equilibrium was established.

Answer (score 0):

The average pressure across the entire bottom will remain constant.

The pressure over any small area may differ.  In this case, the pressure underneath the rock may be larger than the averag.  If so, the pressure over the rest of the pool bottom must be less than the average.

All of the portions of the pool bottom that is in contact with water will have a gauge pressure of $\rho g h$.  Any portion of the pool bottom that is touching a rock instead may have a greater pressure.

Answer (score -1):

The formula for the pressure you give is not valid in all circumstances. In this particular problem it does not apply since the water column is not constant. In other words, this relation is only true, if the water column is constant.

You can see that this formula does not apply in general from the following: The pressure at the bottom of the swimming pool is constant, even though the column height of water below the boat is smaller than next to the boat.
Since this formula does not apply here, there is no contradiction: the mass of water is constant, and therefore also the pressure stays the same.

As an aside, for all of this reasoning we assume that the mass of the rock is negligible. If the rock has a large mass compared to the water, then the pressure at the bottom will increase at the point where the rock touches the bottom.

Edit: Changed 'lake' to 'swimming pool'

Comment: Re, "...at the point where the rock touches bottom" The question could be a tiny bit more specific, but it seems like a safe bet that "pressure" refers to the _water_ pressure, and not the additional pressure on the bottom where it directly supports the weight of the rock.

Comment: Also, the question said, "swimming pool," not "lake." In a lake, with a potentially vast volume of water, and with a continuous inflow and outflow of water, the effect that floating boats have on the water level is negligible in the short term, and _zero_ in the long run (because of equillibrium between inflow and outflow.) The effect of floating a boat in a much smaller swimming pool that contains a fixed volume of water is more dramatic.

Comment: What do mean by “*the water column is not constant*”? Why do you think $P=P_0+\rho g h$ doesn’t apply under the boat? (Here, $P_0$ is the pressure applied by the boat, and $h$ is the depth from the bottom of the boat.)

Comment: Imagine the boat is very deep (almost touches the ground of the swimming pool). Do you then assume that the water pressure below is much lower than the water pressure at the surrounding bottom?

Comment: By "The water column is not constant." I mean the following: If I take a point at the bottom of the swimming pool, I can calculate the water that is above that point. That will give be a variable that has units of mass per surface. This is also sometimes called the water column. If you have a swimming pool that is 3m deep, you have a water column of 3m. Now, if there is a boat in the swimming pool, the water column changes for points at the bottom below the boat (since the distance between the bottom and the water surface now is smaller). The water pressure however will remain constant.